# Host hidden service without accepting incoming connections?

Tags: onion-services, network-configuration

So I am building a p2p network, it will be almost entirely comprised of nodes running on mobile phones and so therefore they will not have public IP addresses and will not be able to accept incoming connections. This poses a problem for p2p networking, as nodes need to be able to receive requests from one another. I am interested in whether it is possible to make each node an tor hidden service and have it connect to the Tor network without needing to accept incoming connections and simple "pull" data from other Tor nodes.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it would work. You do not need public IP and ability to accept incoming connections to run hidden service.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of any libraries that would allow for Tor hidden service integration for either python or node.js?

Comment: Client connecting to hidden service needs to send its request using SOCKS 5 to running tor usually at local host . It can be done by incorporating library with SOCKS 5 support or by using wrapper on unmodified executable. For python there is pysocks module.